# Paypal Adaptive - Pay API

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

When a PAY request is initialised, and the CREATE action type is used, does the PAY API create a payment request under the user's account (ie the user see a payment request under his my account when he logs into paypal?)

Or does this create a PAY request for the API only not a actual money request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later.  In fact, the sender is an optional parameter for this call, only the recipient is required.  However, if you specify yourself as the sender, I believe that makes the call implicit and generates an actual payment without sending you to paypal (though I haven't tested that).